# Excel Web Api Ribbon Button with Dropdown List

Tags: office-js, exceljs, excel-web-addins

I would like to create a dropdown menu on the Ribbon with Excel Web API.
In Microsoft documentation, there is an example of how to make it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/control

```
<Control xsi:type="Menu" id="TestMenu2">
```

The problem is that this button works similar to, for example, **Insert >> Illustrations >> Pictures**, that when I click the button it shows dropdown, but if there is a way like, for example, **Data >> Outline >> Group**, so there are two separate buttons, one for action and the other one for the dropdown menu?

Is there a way to do this in Excel Web API?

This is what I have:
[image]

This is what I need:
[image]

Comment: I don't see a difference between **Insert >> Illustrations >> Pictures** and **Data >> Outline >> Group**. Please provide screenshots so we can see what you mean.

Comment: I added pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there's no way at this time to duplicate that effect with Office Web Add-ins. But it is an interesting idea. You can suggest it at [Microsoft Q&A for Office Web Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/office-addins-dev.html).